# Sticky panels on a desktop web app. Conventions and debate

Tags: navigation, footers, fixed-header

**Is anyone aware of current debate or conventions on the use of sticky headers/footers in web apps?**

I'm designing a screen for trading investments.  This is an inherently complex task for most users.  Steering them to the next activity with an obvious CTA is quite difficult given how much the user has to see.  I'm experimenting with a sticky footer to hold a summary of the users trade instructions with an obvious 'submit trade' button.

Has anyone got any good links to examples of this done well?

Comment: https://www.peakusability.com.au/articles/mobile-ux-part-2-sticky-headers-and-menus talks about mobile... and sticky winning.

Comment: If you're going to implement a sticky header or footer, please don't make it as large as the [SanDisk IT Blog header](https://itblog.sandisk.com/). That thing is huge, and takes up far too much space at the top of the page. Ideally, you only want a sticky header or footer that takes up as much space as it needs, otherwise you'll annoy users with how much space is wasted.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a yes or a no answer i think it depends on the content you intent it hold and the context of it within your use case.

I personally like sticky headers and footers for keeping say favorites at the top of a list or something like that. There are a few articles about the pro's and cons's but the are focused on websites and most on simple nav. i would try a few simple wireframes and see how that feels.

Comment: Definitely.  I've already mocked a lot.  Interesting debate about the value of sticky headers and footers.  Especially in an enterprise app environment where navigation consistency has to be applied. i.e. other areas of app doing similar behaviour.

For example, I've been pushed to a header only sticky arrangement but the user flow is such that they are working through functions down the page and need to see a submit button (which is actually above them).

Thanks for your comment.